# Dynamically populating the dropdown menus in PHP Cake. Access Model from another Model?

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-model

I am building a Cake PHP application. Different users have different properties so I use two objects to store a user for example

- User hasOne Student / Student belongs to User
- User hasOne Lecturer / Lecturer belongs to User

The profile edit page will allow the User to edit all their details for both objects. I've set up the form and used saveAll so save both objects. My problem is dynamically populating the dropdown menus depending on which role the user has.

For example the counties field. Admin does not have an address whereas Student and Lecturer do. I have setup my Country model to find all my counties and put them into opt-groups in the select box (sorting them by country as shown here [Dropdown list with dyanmic optgroup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1873997/dropdown-list-with-dyanmic-optgroup/1877086#1877086))

I can do this fine inside the Students/LecturersController as they allow me to access the Country model as I set $uses variable. I do not want to do this inside the UsersController as not all user roles have an address and an address is never stored inside the User object. I tried putting the code in the model but then I don't know how to access other Models inside a Model. Up to now I've had no problem building the app and I feel that I may have made a bad design decision somewhere or there's something I'm not understanding properly.

Essentially I'm asking how do I implement the `setForForm()` function below.

```
public function edit() {
    //get user
    $user = $this->Auth->user();
    //get role
    $role = $user['User']['role'];
    if ($this->request->is('post') || $this->request->is('put')) {
        //get IDs
        $userID = $user['User']['id'];
        $roleID = $user[$role]['id'];
        //set IDs
        $this->request->data[$role]['user_id'] = $userID;
        $this->request->data[$role]['id'] = $roleID;
        $this->request->data['User']['id'] = $userID;
        //delete data for role that is not theirs
        foreach ($this->request->data as $key => $value) {
            if($key !== 'User' && $key !== $role) {
                unset($this->request->data[$key]);
            }
        }
        if ($this->User->saveAll($this->request->data)) {
            //update logged in user
            $this->Auth->login($this->User->$role->findByUserId($userID));
            $this->Session->setFlash('Changes saved successfully.');
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('Please try again.'));
        }
    }
    //set role for easy access
    $this->set(compact('role'));
    //sets required variables for role form
    $this->User->$role->setForForm();
    //fills in form on first request
    if (!$this->request->data) {
        $this->request->data = $user;
    }
    //render form depending on role
    $this->render(strtolower('edit_' . $role));
}

//this is the method I would like to implement in the Student/Lecturer model somehow
public function setForForm() {
    $counties = $this->Country->getCountiesByCountry();
    $homeCounties = $counties;
    $termCounties = $counties;
    $this->set(compact('homeCounties', 'termCounties'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I get your question correct, but I think what you want is the following:

```
User hasOne Student / Student belongs to User
```

and

```
Student hasOne Country / Country belongsTo Student
```

(and the same for Lectureres)

then from your UsersController you can do:

```
$this->User->Student->Country->findCountiesByCountry();
```

hope that helps

--
EDIT:

if you want to want to use $role instead of Student/Lecturer you would have to do it like this:

```
$this->User->{$role}->Country->findCountiesByCountry();
```

Comment: Trouble with this is that Admin does not have a country so this would not work

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
public function setForForm() {
    App::import('model', 'Country');
    $Country = New Country();
    $counties = $Country->getCountiesByCountry();
    $homeCounties = $counties;
    $termCounties = $counties;
    $this->set(compact('homeCounties', 'termCounties'));
}
```

I don't know is this the best solution or not but it is working at least :)

Edited

Here is another mistake. Its not recommended to set variable from model to view , you can return data that will be set then in edit function normally set it to the view , but anyways if you need to set from model to the view you can load controller class to your model using `App::import();` and use set function.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I decided to just load counties in the user controller regardless of whether the form will need them or not since Admin is the only user that doesn't need them.