# Cakephp DropDown with Parent and child

Tags: php, cakephp, combobox, formhelper

To begin here is an example of what I want to achieve using cake-php way to create a combo-box populated from two tables categories and subcategories.

```
-- Category1
 --- Subcategory1
 --- Subcategory2
 --- ...
-- Category2
 --- Subcategory1
 --- Subcategory2
 --- ...
```

In my Controller I tried to get list of categories with their subcategories using the code bellow but it didn't work and it just returning the List of Subcategories:

```
$this->set('category',($this->category->subcategory->find('list')));
```

Here is the associations I'm using between models:

## category model

```
<?php

class category extends AppModel{

        public $hasMany=array(

                'subcategory'=>array(
                        'className'=>'subcategories',

                    )

            );

}
```

## subcategory model

```
<?php

class subcategory extends AppModel{


    public $belongsTo=array(

        'category'=>array(
                'className'=>'categories',
                'foreignKey'=> 'categories_id'
            )

        );


}
```

I hope my question is clear and thanks a lot.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dropdown list with dynamic optgroup](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1873997/dropdown-list-with-dyanmic-optgroup)

Answer (score 0):

```
$options = array();
foreach($this->Category->find('all') as $key => $category) {
     $options[$category['Category']['name']] = $this->Category->SubCategory->find('list')
}
$this->set('category', $options);
```

Comment: thanks for your answer , anyway it didnt work as expected each category is populated with all subcategories , when i debug the $this->Category->SubCategory->find('list') , only subcategories are returned in the array like this : 
array(
 (int) 1010 => 'Appartements',
 (int) 1020 => 'Maisons et Villas',
 (int) 1030 => 'Locations de vacances',
 (int) 1040 => 'not found',
 (int) 1050 => 'Bureaux et Plateaux',
 (int) 1060 => 'Magasins et Commerces'

Comment: Whats does it look like when you pr($this->Category->find('all', array('contain' => 'SubCategory'))) ?

Comment: here is the returned array : 
array(
 (int) 0 => array(
  'category' => array(
   'id' => '1000',
   'title' => 'IMMOBILIER'
  ),
  'subcategories' => array(
   (int) 0 => array(
    'id' => '1010',
    'title' => 'Appartements',
    'categories_id' => '1000'
   ),....

Answer (score 0):

```
    $data = $this->Category->find('all', array('contain' => 'SubCategory'));
    $categories = array();
    foreach ($data as $key => $category) {
        $categories[$category['category']['title']] = array();
        foreach($category['subcategories'] as $subcategory) {
            array_push($categories[$category['category']['title']], $subcategory['title']);
        }
    }

    pr($categories);
```